# Launch Image working on iPhone 4 & 5 but not on iPhone 6 and 6 plus in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios8, splash-screen

I've set launch images by going in Asset Catalog for  iPhone 4,5, 6 and 6 plus. I know the dimensions for images and I've used them correctly. I've named the launch image for iPhone 6 and 6+, Default-667h@2x.png and Default-736h@3x.png respectively. But still the launch images that I've set for iPhone 6 and 6 plus are not working where as the images for iPhone 4 & 5 are showing up. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple removed LaunchImage from iOS 8. Now if you want to show splash screen you need to use LaunchScreen.xib which now is creating with new project or another xib or storyboard that can be selected in "App Icons and Launch Images" section in "General" tab of your project settings.

[image]

From [developer docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/chapters/AddingLaunchImagestoanAssetCatalog.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013303-CH8-SW1): "On iOS 8, the launch screen file will be used, and on iOS 7, the launch images will be used."
Docs for launch screen [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH28-SW3).

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I didn't knew that so I deleted that LaunScreen.xib in the beginning only. So, is there anyway I can add it back?

Comment: Create a xib file, then set it as the Launch Screen file in the General Tab of the project settings.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by emptying the text box in front of Launch Screen File.
Though it will work if I add the image on LaunchScreen.xib, but for those of you who don't want that xib they need to left the Launch Screen File nil.